# Which is the best way to do this, PHP constant that is accessable in all files but declared in one file?

Tags: php

Which is the best way to do this, PHP constant that is accessable in all files but declared in one file?

file A.php

```
    const MAX_VIDEOS = 4;
```

which is accessable in:

file B.php

```
    $maxvideosplusone = MAX_VIDEOS + 1;
```

if you have an object oriented suggestion to this problem even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the const keyword is meant for CLASS use. If you want to call it then you will need to do MyClass::CONSTANT. If you are using a procedural approach then you need to use the [define function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). For example:

```
define('MAX_VIDEOS', 4);
```

In `file A.php` and use an [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) in `file B.php`:

```
include('file A.php');
```

Comment: Your right about using class constants, thank you, you have helped me. Thats why I have chosen your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just define the variable in one file, then include it in any other files:

The file where it's defined. (file A.php)

```
<?php
    define('MAX_VIDEOS', 4);
?>
```

The file including the constant (file B.php)

```
<?php
    include_once("fileconstants.php");

    print MAX_VIDEOS + 1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [define()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) like this:

```
define('MAX_VIDEOS', 4);
```

And since PHP 5.3 you can use the const keyword also outside of classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
define("MY_VAR", $value);
```

Usage:

```
MY_VAR;
```